# Using Oraclize to ask a question with input variables

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles

I wish to use Oraclize to get prices for different ticker symbols. From the example

```
contract KrakenPriceTicker is usingOraclize {

    string public ETHXBT;

    event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newKrakenPriceTicker(string price);


    function KrakenPriceTicker() {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
        update();
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result, bytes proof) {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        ETHXBT = result;
        newKrakenPriceTicker(ETHXBT);
        update();
    }

    function update() payable {
        if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
    } else {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
        }
    }

}
```

I wish to modify this contract to take a symbol as an input, not ETHXBT. I see the oraclize_query to have a fixed string, how can the query be changed to allow this?

```
oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
```

I also wish to extent this with multiple arguments if requested in input, as an example

> https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT&result=1

How to add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a symbol as an input, you can use the utils present in the oraclizeAPI, such as strConcat, which helps you concatenate strings:

`oraclize_query(60, "URL", strConcat("json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=", symbol,").result.", symbol,".c.0"));`

If you want to receive multiple pairs prices at the same time via the Krakn API you can use the JSONPath. For example,

`json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT,ETHUSD&result=1).result.["XETHXXBT","XETHZUSD"].c.0`

will return the current prices of ETH/BTC and ETH/USD as an array ([test here](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKEdFVCk=:anNvbihodHRwczovL2FwaS5rcmFrZW4uY29tLzAvcHVibGljL1RpY2tlcj9wYWlyPUVUSFhCVCxFVEhVU0QmcmVzdWx0PTEpLnJlc3VsdC5bIlhFVEhYWEJUIiwiWEVUSFpVU0QiXS5jLjA=)).

To parse the result string and convert it to an array you should use the [string-utils solidity library](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils).